# Mockito: Confusion Over MockedStatic

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

The only thing worse than "My code doesn't work and I have no idea why" is "My code works and I have no idea why."

The test in the below code snippet only runs if mockStatic() is called in beforeAll(), despite the fact that **the instance it returns is never used.** (This is the crux of what's hanging me up- see comment in code below)

Based on everything I've read, we should have to do something like `mockedStaticRepo.when(Repository::getInstance).thenReturn(repository)` to explicitly tell Mockito to return the mocked `repository`.

Can someone help me understand what is going on here?

Edit: Using Mockito Core 4.8.0

---

```java
    @Mock
    Application application;

    @Mock
    SomeListener listener;

    @Mock
    RepositoryInterface repository;

    // Why is this necessary, even though the instance is never used?
    static MockedStatic<Repository> mockedStaticRepo;

    ViewModel viewModel;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeAll()
    {
        mockedStaticRepo = mockStatic(IdsRepository.class);
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach()
    {
        when(Repository.getInstance(this.application)).thenReturn(repository);

        ViewModel.Factory factory =
               new ViewModel.Factory(this.application, listener);

        viewModel = spy(factory.create(ViewModel.class));
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void afterAll()
    {
        mockedStaticRepo.close();
    }

    @Test
    void testListenerOperation()
    {
        viewModel.operation();

        verify(listener).onOperation();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the extra information that made it click for me in [the documentation for MockedStatic<T>](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.4.3/org/mockito/MockedStatic.html).

> If the Mock annotation is used on fields or method parameters of this type, a static mock is created instead of a regular mock.

In other words, `MockStatic()` isn't changing the behavior of `MockitoCore::when(...).thenReturn(...)`. It is changing the behavior of the `@Mock` annotation, such that `repository` is a static mock within the scope that `mockStatic()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Please compare

[MockitoCore.when](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/5486617f7ac759d24e99ee9d8d03e969acdd460f/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/MockitoCore.java#LL171C55-L171C55)

```java
public <T> OngoingStubbing<T> when(T methodCall) {
    MockingProgress mockingProgress = mockingProgress();
    mockingProgress.stubbingStarted();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    OngoingStubbing<T> stubbing = (OngoingStubbing<T>) mockingProgress.pullOngoingStubbing();
    if (stubbing == null) {
        mockingProgress.reset();
        throw missingMethodInvocation();
    }
    return stubbing;
}
```

[MockedStaticImpl.when](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/5486617f7ac759d24e99ee9d8d03e969acdd460f/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/MockedStaticImpl.java#LL45C40-L45C52)

```java
public <S> OngoingStubbing<S> when(Verification verification) {
    assertNotClosed();

    try {
        verification.apply();
    } catch (MockitoException exception) {
        throw exception;
    } catch (Throwable ignored) {
    }

    MockingProgress mockingProgress = mockingProgress();
    mockingProgress.stubbingStarted();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    OngoingStubbing<S> stubbing = (OngoingStubbing<S>) mockingProgress.pullOngoingStubbing();
    if (stubbing == null) {
        mockingProgress.reset();
        throw missingMethodInvocation();
    }
    return stubbing;
}
```

Notice that the differences boil down to:

- checking that MockedStatic instance is not closed
- different argument to the when call

  - MockitoCore takes a result of a method call on a mock
  - MockedStatic takes a lambda (which should call a method on a mock), and calls the lambda
  - the api difference is discussed in [Enable mocking static methods in Mockito #1013](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1013)
  - there is also an open ticket to [Support lambda when syntax #643](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/643) in Mockito Core

As you can see, the actual work is identical in both methods, which is why your code works with MockitoCore version

Comment: I think this gets me part of the way there, but ultimately I still fail to understand how calling MockStatic() causes MockitoCore::when() to behave differently. I've edited the question to (hopefully) clarify

Comment: I figured it out and posted in another answer. Thanks for taking the time to help!